# With SSRS, is it possible to bind to a custom datasource (List<T>) and include properties of related entities on a report?

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

We have a custom datasource that returns a List of our objects (uses Entity Framework). Our object has related objects (which we include in our query), defined through foreign keys (and navigation properties in Entity Framework). When we attach the data to an SSRS report, we can see all of the properties, including the navigation properties, but we haven't found a way to successfully display the properties on related objects in our report.

For example, say our datasource returns List. We can put Customer.Name on the report, but is there a way to add the Customer.Type.Name? In the datasource, it seems to recognize the virtual property "Type" as a "CustomerType" object that we've defined, but it doesn't recognize that it's a reference to another type of object with it's own properties.

Also note, we are using ReportViewer (local) control, not remote server processing.

Comment: I doubt it. Those datasets are going to be flat like database tables. I'm afraid that you are going to have to flatten out your data or use multiple datasets.

Comment: Thanks, Ross. I haven't found anything that suggests otherwise, so you're quite possibly right.